# Regex - new line that is not followed by time

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to preform a preg_replace for every empty line that is not followed by this:

```
00:00:02.800 --> 00:00:04.800
```

Its format is:

```
any 2 digits:any 2 digits:any 2 digits.any 3 digits --> any 2 digits:any 2 digits:any 2 digits.any 3 digits
```

I know how to search for  an empty line:

```
"/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/"
```

And for the  time row :

```
[0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[:][0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[:][0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[.][0-9]{1,3}[:.,-]?[\s][-][-][>][\s][0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[:][0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[:][0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?[.][0-9]{1,3}[:.,-]?
```

But I wasn't able to create a regex that finds only the lines that are not followed by the time row.

EDIT:
OPTION 1
File Input:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.300 --> 00:00:01.000
line1
  
line2
line3

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:02.800
line1

00:00:02.800 --> 00:00:04.800
line1
line2


line3
```

File desired output:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.300 --> 00:00:01.000
line1  
line2
line3

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:02.800
line1

00:00:02.800 --> 00:00:04.800
line1
line2
line3
```

My function:

```
 $content = preg_replace("/regex expresion/", "", $file_content);
```

EDIT 2:

Just found out I need to find another format:
OPTION 2
File Input:

```
1
00:00:00,300 --> 00:00:01,000
line 1 line 1

line 2

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,800
line 1 line 1 line 1

line2


line 3 line 3

3
00:00:02,800 --> 00:00:04,800
line 1
```

File desired output:

```
1
00:00:00,300 --> 00:00:01,000
line 1 line 1
line 2

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,800
line 1 line 1 line 1
line2
line 3 line 3

3
00:00:02,800 --> 00:00:04,800
line 1
```

Totos answer worked great. I tried to modify it to my need and was unsuccessful.
I tried:

```
/(\R){1,}(?!(\d\R\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}) --> (?2))
```

---

## Solved

Solution:

option 1:

```
$regex = "/(\R){1,}(?=(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}) --> (?2))/";
```

option 2:

```
$regex = "/(\R)(?!(\d\R\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\,\d{3}))/";
```

Comment: can you please provide raw data sample and expected result?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/YztJiZ/2

Comment: `(([0-9]{1,3}[:.]??){4})([\s->]+)(([0-9]{1,3}[:.]??){4})` Slightly off topic but using something like this to match the time string will avoid the large amount of repition

Comment: @Alex Thank you. 
That is the closest I got to a solution. 
The only problem is that it replaces all new lines except the one before the time row.

Comment: @Alex I have added an example input an desired output. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like [`/^\h*\R(?!\d+:)/m`](https://regex101.com/r/yKYzhl/1/) would suffice. See [php demo](https://eval.in/1041059).

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = <<<EOD
1
00:00:00,300 --> 00:00:01,000
line 1 line 1

line 2

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,800
line 1 line 1 line 1

line2


line 3 line 3

3
00:00:02,800 --> 00:00:04,800
line 1
EOD;

$str =preg_replace('/(\R)+(?!\d)/', '$1', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output for given example:**

```
00:00:00,300 --> 00:00:01,000
line 1 line 1
line 2

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,800
line 1 line 1 line 1
line2
line 3 line 3

3
00:00:02,800 --> 00:00:04,800
line 1
```

**Explanation:**

```
(\R)+       : group 1, any kind of linebreak, 2 or more times
(?!\d)      : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have digit after
```

Or, if lineX could begin with digit:

```
$str =preg_replace('/(\R){2,}(?!(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}) --> (?2)|\d+)\R/', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: Hey, It worked on one liner, For a more complex text it worked after I clanged  (\R){2,}  to (\R){1,} . 

I also need (Sorry found out today) do the same change for lines like this:
5\n
00:00:02.800 --> 00:00:04.800\n

Comment: I edited my question and added what I meant. Thank you so much - I really need to get my regex skills improved.

Comment: Will it work if some of the lines will start whit a number. 
Instead off 'line 1' there will be '1 line...'?

Comment: @matisa: It deletes linebreak before "time" or a lines that don't contain only digits.

Comment: Well unfortunately I can not rule out that lines will start with a number because those are subtitles. I have no knowledge of what the line will contain - but I know that a line with number followed by time row will always be a new sun indicator.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/feqs76/3/

```
\n\n(\D|!(^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))
```

or probably in your case

```
\r\n(\D|!(^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))
```

**UPDATE** PHP

https://ideone.com/hRYizH

```
$regexp = '/(\R)(\R*)(\D|!(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))/';
$content = preg_replace($regexp, "\n$3", $file_content);
```

Comment: Hey, Tnx.
It looks like it should work but in php preg_replace it does nothing.
My func: 
$file_content = preg_replace("/\r\n(\D|!(^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))/", "$$$$$$$", $file_content);

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work

`$pattern = \n{2,}(?=\D|(^(([0-9]{1,3}[:.]??){4})([\s->]+)(([0-9]{1,3}[:.]??){4})))`

[Example Here](http://regexr.com/3stub)

`preg_replace($pattern, "", $string)`